# Get the bound route model instance in a generic parent class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1's [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-model-binding) to infer/instantiate the correct model instance from the routes.

I don't want to rewrite a `show()` method for each resource, and would rather call parent `show()` method in a generic parent class. The problem is, I don't know how to allow my parent class's `show()` method to infer the correct model instance, so I'm forced to create a `show()` on each child resource and specify the model (like below, `User $user`).

How can I get the bound model in my controllers from the binding in `RouteServiceProvider`: `App\User`? And pass it through to the parent `show()` method?

---

Route:

```
// Passing in id 1 for {user}
$router->get('/users/{user}', 'Resources\Users@show');
```

RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    $router->model('user', 'App\User');
}
```

UsersController.php: **How I am currently doing it**

```
class User extends ResourceController
{

    public function show(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        // Returns user of ID 1 as expected
        return $user;
    }
```

ResourceController.php: **How I'd like to do it**

```
class ResourceController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Request $request, Model $model)
    {
        // Infer "Users" model here and returns User with ID 1
        return $model;
    }
```

Comment: maybe add right before `$router->model` a biding? `app()->bind(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class, App\User::class);`. On other routes you'd bind different models.

Comment: I would like to just provide my 2 cents, if you'd hear me out. The method that you're going about is actually working against the `Dependency Injection` design paradigm. Instead, you should still make the controllers, but you should have a `trait` that the controllers `use`. This trait should provide the generic functionality for returning data, while allowing for overriding the methods on a case by case basis.